# Matrix with elements different from zero only on the main diagonal and antidiagonal c++

Tags: c++, class, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
1 0 0 2
0 1 2 0
0 5 3 0
1 0 0 2
```

I store them in a

```
vector<int>v
```

From

```
v[0][0] - v[n][n] + v[0][n] - v[n][0]
```

Here is how i try to read the matrix

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const Xmatrix& a)
{
unsigned int matrixSize;
s >> matrixSize;
a.reSize(matrixSize);
    int x = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i) {
        s >> a(i,i);
    }
    for(unsigned int i = matrixSize - 1; i > matrixSize + 1; --i) {
        if(x == matrixSize / 2){
            x = x + 2;
            s >> a(x,i);
        }
        else{
            s >> a(x,i);
            x++;
        }
    }

return s;
}
```

And here is how i try to do the multiplication

```
Xmatrix operator*(const Xmatrix& a ,const Xmatrix& b)
{
if(a._v.size() != b._v.size()){
    throw Xmatrix::DIFFERENT;
}

Xmatrix c(a._v.size());
int x = a._v.size();
int m = x/2;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < c._v.size(); ++i){
    //c._v[i] = a._v[i] * b._v[i];
    c._v[i] = a._v[i] * b._v[i] + a._v[i] * b._v[x+i] + a._v[m] * b._v[x+i] + a._v[m] * b._v[i];
    x--;
    m++;
}
return c;
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work,it gives really stupid numbers

Did i store the elements and did the calc right?

I did this with classes

Comment: `o` in `ostream` stands for "output". You are trying to read from an output stream.

Comment: Please note the posted code defines `operator<<` (and the matrix is passed as a `const` reference), while it should be `operator>>`, if you are trying to read the matrix.

Comment: `if(x == matrixSize / 2){x = x + 2;` Why this special case? What in your opinion makes `matrixSize / 2` different and warrants skipping a value? After such a skip, `a(x,i)` no longer lies on the anti-diagonal.

Comment: @Bob__ I copied wrong line,but thats fine in my code